# Tar (or archive) folders that contain specific files and transfer to another directory

Tags: bash, find, tar, archive, file-transfer

I'm looking to tar or archive a lot of data to transfer it to a new location on Ubuntu 16LTS.

> Data structure:

```
Directory
├── docs
├── results
│   └── results.txt
├── participant_A1
│   ├── sequence_1
│   │   ├── xyz.IMA
│   │   ├── xyz2.IMA
│   │   ├── xyz3.IMA
│   │   └── ...IMA
│   ├── sequence_2
│   │   ├── xyz2.IMA
│   │   ├── xyz3.IMA
│   │   └── ...IMA  
│   
├── participant_B2
│   ├── sequence_3
│   │   ├── xyz.IMA
│   │   ├── xyz2.IMA
│   │   ├── xyz3.IMA
│   │   └── ...IMA
│   ├── sequence_4
│   │   ├── xyz2.IMA
│   │   ├── xyz3.IMA
│   │   └── ...IMA
│   │   ...etc
```

My issue is that I need to archive the folders containing .IMA files before rsync'ing due to inode limits.

- I want to keep the data structure intact.
- I want to tar all the *.IMA files for each subdirectory and keep the archive in their folders (there are several thousand per 'sequence').
- All the "participants" are named randomly.
- The "sequence" name is also variable between participants.
- The rest of the data can be transferred without archiving.

I figure i can do something like: 
`find / -type f -name "*IMA" -exec tar -rf archive.tar '{}' \;` but I don't know how to keep the data structure intact with variable folder names.

> Expected result:

```
Directory
├── docs
├── results
│   └── results.txt
├── participant_A1
│   ├── sequence_1.tar.gz
│   ├── sequence_2.tar.gz
│   
├── participant_B2
│   ├── sequence_3.tar.gz
│   ├── sequence_4.tar.gz
│   │   ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my inelegant solution. This will go into a directory (in_dir), then search that directory for any directories that contain .IMA files. Each folder that contains IMAs will be archived. The entire top level directory is sent to $out_dir, excluding the folders that contian .IMA files (using the --exclude flag of tar). Then the archived folders are deleted to save space.

```
#!/bin/bash
in_dir=~/test_in_dir
out_dir=~/test_out_dir
```

Find all the folders that have IMA files in them

```
find ${in_dir} -name '*.IMA' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
```

Loop over the directories and make it into an array

```
cd $in_dir
i=0
shopt -s dotglob
shopt -s nullglob
array=(`find . -name '*.IMA' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u`)
for dir in "${array[@]}" ; do
    echo "$dir"
    (( i++))
done
```

Loop through the array $i number of times and tar each folder as you do it.

```
j=0
while ((j < $i)) ; do
    cd $in_dir
    cd ${array[$j]}
    folder=${PWD##*/}
    cd ../
    tar cfz ${folder}.tar.gz ${folder}/*
    (( j++ ))
done
```

Send the whole directory to out_dir but excluding all the directories in the array

```
exclude_options=()
for x in "${array[@]}"; do
  exclude_options+=(--exclude="$x")
done
cd $in_dir
tar -czvf $out_dir/transferred_from_in.tar.gz "${exclude_options[@]}" ./
```

rm all the tar files in the in_dir to save space

```
for y in "${array[@]}"; do
    rm -r ${y}.tar.gz  
done
```